# GKE won't scale down to a single node

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've seen other similar questions, but none that quite address our specific case that as far as I can tell.

We have a cluster where we run development environments. When we're not working, ideally, that cluster should go down to a single node. At the moment, no one is working, and I can see that there is one node where CPU/Mem/Disk are essentially at 0 percent, with only system pods on it. The other node has some stuff on it.

The cluster is setup to autoscale down to 1. Why won't it do so?

It will autoscale up to however many we need when we spin up new environments and down to 2 no problem. But down to 1? No dice. When I manually delete the node with only system pods, and basically 0 usage, the cluster spins up a new one. I can't understand why.

**Update/Clarification:**

I've messed around with the configuration, so I'm not sure exactly what system pods were running, but I'm almost certain they were all DaemonSet-controlled. So, even after manually destroying a node, having everything non-system rescheduled, a new node would still pop up with no workloads specifically triggering the scale-up to 2.

Just to make sure I wasn't making things up, I've re-organized things so that there's just a single node running with no autoscaling, and it has plenty of excess capacity with everything running nicely. As far as I can tell, nothing new got scheduled onto that single node.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might not have checked limitation of GKE scaling down section. No issues please check and read once you might need to change the **PDB** **(Pod distribution budget)** once.

> Occasionally, the cluster autoscaler cannot scale down completely and
> an extra node exists after scaling down. This can occur when required
> system Pods are scheduled onto different nodes, because there is no
> trigger for any of those Pods to be moved to a different node. See I
> have a couple of nodes with low utilization, but they are not scaled
> down. Why?. To work around this limitation, you can configure a Pod disruption budget.

By default, kube-system pods prevent `Cluster Autoscaler` from removing nodes on which they are running. Users can manually add PDBs for the kube-system pods that can be safely rescheduled elsewhere:

```
kubectl create poddisruptionbudget <pdb name> --namespace=kube-system --selector app=<app name> --max-unavailable 1
```

You can read more at : https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-to-set-pdbs-to-enable-ca-to-move-kube-system-pods

Don't forget to checkout limitation of GKE scaling : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#limitations

Comment: I think I saw that one (the GKE-specific doc) and I'm not sure I understand it in this context. I think the only system pods running were DaemonSet-controlled. The thing that's confusing is that I destroyed the second node, and everything that wasn't DaemonSet-controlled got re-scheduled. But a new node popped up anyway. Maybe I'm misunderstanding or misreading the doc you sent? I could understand if I _hadn't_ destroyed the node, and there were things running on it. Also, if relevant, I'm using the optimize-utilization autoscaling profile. (I say "were" because I just re-configured things)

Comment: did you check your PDB config ? could be possible due to that pod scaled again and your new node joind the cluster.

Comment: I believe PDBs for system pods will solve the problem with the setup you have/had, but alternatively, you may want to use Node Auto-provisioning rather than a nodepool with cluster autoscaler.

You may also want to try using Autopilot as well as in that case you'll only be paying for the resources consumed by running pods not the compute resources of the nodes themselves.